# Current post categories and subcatecories outside of the loop

Tags: posts, categories, loop

What I would like to achieve is getting the posts categories and subcategories (without needing subcategories to be related to this post) (when viewing the post) in a list outside of the loop, preferably in a sidebar widget. I want it to get updated automatically when displaying different posts without needing the user to specify the categories or posts manually from back-end. I tried with GLOBALS but couldn't get it to work.

Anyone done anything like this before? How should I approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()` should return the id, Just tested with my stock _s theme. `var_dump(get_queried_object_id());` returning `int(9511) `. Are you sure your sidebar or something else is not modifying the query? Can you try `wp_reset_postdata()` before your code?

Comment: @SahriarSaikat thanks for your reply, I will remove the code - above code returns sub-categories only if they are associated with the post. Does nothing like what I want. I am at the beginning again.

Comment: Dump get_queried_object_id() in sidebar and see what it returns

Comment: It returns the page id, correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your sidebar.php. I highly recommend you to use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Here is a minimum example of such a tag list. you can also make a widget out of it. [Learn here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/).

And add html based on your theme's design structure.

```
<ul>
<?php 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'taxonomy-name-here' );
foreach($terms as $term){
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/rdtt83 this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You post this code in sidebar.php

Comment: I have added more info

Comment: Won't this display only terms related to the post?

Comment: And Stackoverflow is more about solving your problems, not asking others to do your homework, please do your research first.

Comment: Sorry if mistaken, having you to do my homework was not my intension. Thanks.

Comment: You are constantly modifying your initial post and demanding new functionality. I highly suggest you to have a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: "Won't this display only terms related to the post?" Yes

Comment: Again, sorry I just edited the question after realizing I didn't state it correctry. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You should start a new question since Your current question is totally different from what you initially asked.